# How do you get the URL out of a http.client.HTTPResponse object?

Tags: python, urllib

(Using python3.4)

Lets say you ran some code like this:

```
from urllib import request
some_url = request.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
```

After accessing the url .../wiki/Special:Random the url will promptly change to something like .../wiki/Python_(programming_language).  How would you get the new url out of some_url?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.url`:

```
>>> from urllib import request
>>> r = request.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
>>> r.url
'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_Mountain'
```

or `.geturl()`:

```
>>> r.geturl()
'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_Mountain'
```